# Error with nucleusexception and jdofatalexception when starting hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, hadoop-2.7.2

I am installing hive for the first time on my system with embedded derby metastore but it is not working. It is showing the below mentioned error.

```
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="",sql-type="") cant be mapped for this metastore.No mapping is available.
NestedThrowables    
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="",sql-type="") cant be mapped for this metastore.No mapping is available
```

Please help

Comment: What version of `jdk` are you using?

Comment: openjdk-9-jdk version of java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 9 is not yet supported by Hive. Install either Java 7 or 8 and set the JDK directory as `JAVA_HOME` in the environment where Hive is installed.

**PS:** Prefer MySQL for metastore rather than derby.

**An embedded metastore database is mainly used for unit tests. Only one process can connect to the metastore database at a time, so it is not really a practical solution but works well for unit tests.**